# Elixir, pattern matching

Tags: list, design-patterns, maps, elixir, ecto

I do need help with pattern matching one list of maps. This is how it looks like:

```
  [
  %RewardappWeb.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    april: 50,
    august: 50,
    december: 50,
    february: 50,
    id: 1,
    january: 50,
    july: 50,
    june: 50,
    march: 50,
    may: 50,
    name: "mat",
    november: 50,
    october: 50,
    points: 0,
    role: "member",
    september: 50,
    surname: "osinski"
  },
  %RewardappWeb.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    april: 50,
    august: 50,
    december: 50,
    february: 50,
    id: 2,
    january: 50,
    july: 50,
    june: 50,
    march: 50,
    may: 50,
    name: "dag",
    november: 50,
    october: 50,
    points: 0,
    role: "member",
    september: 50,
    surname: "kaz"
  },
  %RewardappWeb.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    april: 50,
    august: 50,
    december: 50,
    february: 50,
    id: 3,
    january: 50,
    july: 50,
    june: 50,
    march: 50,
    may: 50,
    name: "hap",
    november: 50,
    october: 50,
    points: 0,
    role: "member",
    september: 50,
    surname: "dzek"
  },
  %RewardappWeb.User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
    april: 50,
    august: 50,
    december: 50,
    february: 50,
    id: 4,
    january: 50,
    july: 50,
    june: 50,
    march: 50,
    may: 50,
    name: "ter",
    november: 50,
    october: 50,
    points: 0,
    role: "member",
    september: 50,
    surname: "ew"
  }
]
```

I need to find, whether the specific name, which will be given by user is contained in the list. I will be glad, if someone will inform me with the idea how to check then, if the user contains in the mentioned list, and how to store ALL his values (such as months, role, surname etc.) Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Or maybe a different way. User inputs some value (its his name) in the form. Then I want to check, whether my database contains this name - if yes, he is logged, if not, he will be prompted an error. In my database I do have column called name, and there are some values in it. I was trying to do this with repo.exists? but it did not work.

Comment: You absolutely don’t need a pattern matching here. You need [`Enum.find/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3).

Comment: So I have done something like that Enum.find(listOfUsers, fn x -> x == value end), and it has returned nil. Value is value = userp["user"], and %{"user" => userp}

Answer (score 0):

Let's stick with your first question (you added a completely different one later). As has already been said, you absolutely do not need pattern matching to check whether a certain element occurs in a list. This is easily done with [Enum.find/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3). Here is a simple example:

```
iex(1)> users = [%{name: "foo", age: 21}, %{name: "bar", age: 76}]
[%{age: 21, name: "foo"}, %{age: 76, name: "bar"}]
iex(2)> name = "foo"
"foo"
iex(3)> Enum.find(users, fn user -> user.name == name end)
%{age: 21, name: "foo"}
iex(4)> name = "unknown"
"unknown"
iex(5)> Enum.find(users, fn user -> user.name == name end)
nil
```

This should work completely analogous with your example. If you always get back `nil`, your matching condition is very likely wrong.